# Regex to find strings that contain a certain text only once

Tags: regex

I need to find all the lines in a file where a certain text appears exactly once. The text is an occurrence of something like:

```
##somethingVariable##
```

that is, all the time a string is between ## and ##

I am using the following RegEx:

```
(?<!.*<CAPTURE>.*)(?<CAPTURE>##[^#]*##)(?!.*<CAPTURE>.*)
```

I find what i need with

```
##[^#]*##
```

i capture it and name it and i say to find it only if it is not preceded or followed by the same capture text. I also tried with different combinations of ^$ before and after and some .* before and there but it doesnt work.
What am i doing wrong?

Examples:

```
inThisString##THIS##appreasJustOnceAndIWantToFindIt
inThisString##THAT##AppreasTwiceAndIDoNOTWantToFind##THAT##case
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead based regex like this:

```
^(?:(?!##).)*(##[^#]*##)(?!.*?\1).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fL2eW9/2)

This will match first input in your example but won't match the second one.

Comment: Won't this break on an input like `inThis#String##THIS##appreasJustOnceAndIWantToFindIt`?

Comment: If `#` can come in between `##` and `##` then use this regex: `^(?:(?!##).)*(##(?:(?!##).)*##)(?!.*?\1).*$` [Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fL2eW9/3)

Comment: Thx for the answers.Unfortunately it is hard to think of all the cases in advance. In a single row there can be more of these ##texts## and the first part of the Regex where you check if there are no occurrences of ## can't deal with these cases. Example: exampleExample##THISTEXTTWICE##exampleExample##THISTEXTONCE##exexexex##THISTEXTTWICE##exexexexex.  Now that i am writing this comment i am aware of the fact that also the text between these two placeholders could be considered a placeHolder, starting from the final ## of a placeHolder and ending on the first ## of the next placeholder.

Comment: Anyways if there is just one kind of placeholder your RegEx work and i will mark it as an answer to my original question. thx

Comment: @JohannesWentu: Thanks for accepting the answer. And yes your description of more complex cases sounds interesting. Feel free to create a new question with those cases and I would sure like to attend that as well.